# How can I select a bunch of rows with the partition name in each row?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with range partitioning. In PostgreSQL, I could select the `tableoid` column to see which partition each row is in (because with PostgreSQL I have to explicitly use table inheritance to implement partitioning). Is there a similar way to do this in MySQL? Here's roughly what I want (let's assume I have the `orders` table partitioned by year using range partitioning):

```
SELECT orders.cost_usd, orders.partition_name
FROM orders
WHERE orders.year > 2005;
```

And the results would be:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------+
| orders.cost_usd | orders.partition_name |
+-----------------+-----------------------+
|         1039.90 | p_2005                |
|          459.06 | p_2006                |
|          033.77 | p_2006                |
|         6473.36 | p_2008                |
|          240.17 | p_2009                |
|         1011.20 | p_2013                |
+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: What kind of partitioning did you use? It affects the answer.. RANGE, LINEAR KEY??? We need to see your `PARTITION BY` statement.

Answer (score 0):

### INTRO

In order to solve this problem you can make use of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` table.
Especially useful for you will be the `PARTITION_DESCRIPTION` and the `PARTITION_NAME` fields.

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitions-table.html

> PARTITION_DESCRIPTION: This column is used for RANGE and LIST
>   partitions. For a RANGE partition, it contains the value set in the
>   partition's VALUES LESS THAN clause, which can be either an integer or
>   MAXVALUE. For a LIST partition, this column contains the values
>   defined in the partition's VALUES IN clause, which is a
>   comma-separated list of integer values.
>
> For partitions whose PARTITION_METHOD is other than RANGE or LIST,
>   this column is always NULL.

Finally, and **very importantly** - **the exact SQL solution also depends on the *type* of PARTITION that is used.** See [**Partition Types**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html).

### PARTITION BY RANGE

**Example: [Click for SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7781bf/9)**

```
create table orders
(cost_usd double,
 year int
 )
 PARTITION BY RANGE(year)
    (
        PARTITION p_2005 VALUES LESS THAN (2006),
        PARTITION p_2006 VALUES LESS THAN (2007),
        PARTITION p_2007 VALUES LESS THAN (2008),
        PARTITION p_2008 VALUES LESS THAN (2009),
        PARTITION p_2009 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
        PARTITION p_2010 VALUES LESS THAN (2011),
        PARTITION p_2011 VALUES LESS THAN (2012),
        PARTITION p_2012 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
        PARTITION p_2013 VALUES LESS THAN (2014)
 );


insert into orders values (1039.90, 2005);
insert into orders values (459.06, 2006);
insert into orders values (033.77, 2006);
insert into orders values (6473.36, 2008);
insert into orders values (240.17, 2009);
insert into orders values (1011.20, 2013);
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.cost_usd, PartitionInfo2.PARTITION_NAME
FROM orders,    
  ( SELECT orders.year,
           min(CONVERT(p.PARTITION_DESCRIPTION,UNSIGNED INTEGER)) AS rangeMax
   FROM orders,
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS p
   WHERE orders.year < CONVERT(p.PARTITION_DESCRIPTION,UNSIGNED INTEGER)
     AND TABLE_NAME='orders'
   GROUP BY orders.year) AS PartitionInfo,
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS PartitionInfo2
WHERE orders.year = PartitionInfo.year AND
CONVERT(PartitionInfo2.PARTITION_DESCRIPTION,UNSIGNED INTEGER) = 
PartitionInfo.RangeMax;
```

**Results:**

```
COST_USD    PARTITION_NAME
1039.9      p_2005
459.06      p_2006
33.77       p_2006
6473.36     p_2008
240.17      p_2009
1011.2      p_2013
```

### PARTITION BY HASH

**Example: [Click for SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dda34/6)**

Below is an example where there is partitioning by hash, but additionally, we are subtract 2000 from the year integer in order to have partition indexes that start from zero.

```
create table orders
(cost_usd double,
 year int
 )
 PARTITION BY HASH(year-2000) PARTITIONS 20;
```

Essentially, this means we will have 20 partitions that will correctly fit years from 2000 to 2020. Larger values will unfortunately be places in between.

A setup such as the above leads to a much easier solution.

**SQL:**

```
select cost_usd, p.PARTITION_NAME, concat('p_',orders.year) PRETTY_PNAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS p,
orders where
TABLE_NAME='orders' AND
PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION+1999 = orders.year;
```

**Results:**

```
COST_USD    PARTITION_NAME  PRETTY_PNAME
1039.9         p5        p_2005
459.06         p6        p_2006
33.77          p6        p_2006
6473.36        p8        p_2008
240.17         p9        p_2009
1011.2         p13       p_2013
```